# php echo not processing

Tags: php, content-management-system

Firstly, a) I hope I am not asking a stupid question and b) this hasn't been already covered..

For a project I am writing a form of CMS system (basic) for a customer website, but using file_get_contents() and then echo'ing it returns raw html with php tags in it.

Can anyone shed any light on what I am doing wrong please?

```
<?php

require_once( "system/functions.php" );
require_once( "registeredModules.php" ); 
include "system/PageGenerator.php";

$includes = array( "pagePreamble"=>"pageData/index_pagePreamble.inf",
                   "headContents"=>"pageData/index_headContents.inf",
                   "bodyPreamble"=>"pageData/index_bodyPreamble.inf",
                   "contents"=>"pageData/index_contents.inf" );

$pageTitle = "Hook and Odiham Lions";

$html = file_get_contents( $template );

... other processing here....

print $html;

?>
```

Comment: What is the form of `$template`? Is it a file name or a URL? If it is a file name, PHP just gets the file from disk without executing it first. If you want PHP to execute it, you need to use `include`, but be very careful is this is user-supplied code!

Comment: It is a filename ... $template = "templates/hookodihamlions.template";

Comment: `file_get_contents()` just reads the file in as a string. It does not execute that file as PHP code. You need to use `include` or `eval()` for that, depending on what you want to do (possibly in combination with output buffering (see [`ob_start()`](http://be1.php.net/ob_start)) to get the output into a PHP variable instead of directly to a brower). But, *if* this template is user-supplied, it is a bad idea to execute them!

Comment: @Tomas Creemers: The template is supplied by me, the contents is user supplied.  I supply basic website structure and he/she adds the contents in the middle..  Still a bad idea to execute it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with next code for open you template file:

```
function read_data_file( $file ) {
            $file_open = fopen( $file , 'r' );
            $file_data = fread( $file_open , filesize( $file ) );
            fclose( $file_open );

            return $file_data;
        }
```

Usage:

```
$html = read_data_file( $template );
```

Comment: The issue is how do I then get the html/php code to be evaluated after it is returned please?

Comment: You have just partially rewritten [`file_get_contents()`](http://be1.php.net/file_get_contents). :-)

Comment: Is there a way to echo/print the html/php to the browser so the php is processed/parsed?